# Error in XSLT while

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, xpath, soap

I am writing XSLT where I have declared initially current date formatted as Props.

**Defined in XSLT**

```
<xsl:param name="prop.current.date.formatted"></xsl:param>
```

and I have to use this param in declaring the Effective date and how to write in XSLT.

I have written in this way in XSLT  but its showing an error.

**Using in this way in XSLT**

```
 <wd:Address_Data wd:Effective_Date="$prop.current.date.formatted">
```

**Error message**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.validationError</faultcode>
<faultstring>Validation error occurred. Invalid format for date text=$prop.current.date.formatted on attr Communication Method Usage Effective Date or Earliest Created Moment</faultstring>
<detail>
<wd:Validation_Fault>
<wd:Validation_Error>
<wd:Message>Invalid format for date text=$prop.current.date.formatted on attr Communication Method Usage Effective Date or Earliest Created Moment</wd:Message>
<wd:Detail_Message>Invalid format for date text=$prop.current.date.formatted on attr Communication Method Usage Effective Date or Earliest Created Moment</wd:Detail_Message>
<wd:Xpath>/wd:Submit_Supplier_Request[1]/wd:Supplier_Data[1]/wd:Business_Entity_Data[1]/wd:Contact_Data[1]/wd:Address_Data[1]/@wd:Effective_Date</wd:Xpath>
</wd:Validation_Error>
</wd:Validation_Fault>
</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anybody let me know how to define the above prop in XSLT?

For more information let me know.

Thanks
Uday

Answer (score 1):

You have to use attribute substitution if you write it in this (admittetly simple) way:

```
 <wd:Address_Data wd:Effective_Date="{$prop.current.date.formatted}">
```